# Javascript storing value in key value form

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to store value like key and value pair in javascript

So far i am doing  like this

```
var list_of_addressbook_entries = {};

list_of_addressbook_entries.guest_name = name ;

for(key in list_of_addressbook_entries)
{
  alert("key " + key
  + " has value "
  + list_of_addressbook_entries[key]);
}
```

In the above code guest_name is a variable which value is coming from a onclick
so when i am doing the above it showing me the result like

```
 key guest_name has value M
```

it is not printing the value of guest_name

i want the result like

```
key guest_name_variable value  has key M
```

Please suggest me what to do here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood right, you need to use the bracket [] syntax, otherwise it is not interpreted as a variable:

`list_of_addressbook_entries[guest_name] = name ;`

Comment: great one more thing how can i remove a key value pair from the dict ?

Comment: `delete list_of_addressbook_entries[guest_name];`